# unable to install expo dependencies

Tags: reactjs, navigation

unable to install

expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

the following error displayed

C:\test\navigator>expo install @react-native-community/masked-view
Installing 1 SDK 36.0.0 compatible native module using npm.

> npm install
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! syscall spawn git
>   npm ERR! path git
>   npm ERR! errno -4058
>   npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
>   npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
>   npm ERR! enoent
>   npm ERR! enoent
>   npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent

please resolve

Answer (score 0):

Install version 1.5.3. It should work. Seems like the broken patch was published. Run `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler@1.5.3`